# Do we say "to lean the roll of mat AGAINST / ON the corner of the room" or "to lean the roll of mat IN the corner of the room"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

> **[lean](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lean_1?q=lean)** [transitive] to make something rest against something in a sloping position
>
> **lean something against something** Can I lean my bike against the
>   wall?
>
> She leaned her head against his shoulder.
>
> **lean something on something** He leaned his elbows on the table and
>   sighed.
>
> He sat down and leaned his chin on his right hand.

---

> **[corner](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/corner_1?q=corner)**: the place inside a room or a box where two sides join; the area around this place
>
> A large desk occupies another corner of the room.
>
> He found a quiet corner and got on with his work.
>
> **in the corner** They made straight for the table in the corner.
>
> **in the corner of something** She spotted him sitting in the corner
>   of the bar.
>
> We found an empty booth **in** a dark corner of the pub.
>
> There was a television **in** the far corner of the bedroom.
>
> a corner table/seat/cupboard

---

It is very hard to comprehend prepositions in English.

We normally use "**LEAN**" with "**AGAINST**" or "**ON**"

Eg, "**to lean the roll of mat AGAINST / ON the wall**"

But we often use "**CORNER**" with "**IN**"

Eg, "**There is a roll of mat IN the corner of the room**"

See this picture of a broom leaning AGAINST / IN the corner.

[image]

Now, we want to use "**lean**" & "**corner**" in one sentence

Do we say "**to lean the roll of mat AGAINST / ON the corner of the room**" or "**to lean the roll of mat IN the corner of the room**"?

Comment: @OrbitalAussie, I want a "corner object", I don't want a "corner space". How to express a corner object (the line that joins 2 sides)?

Comment: @OrbitalAussie In my vocabulary, a corner is where two walls intersect, at either 90 or 270 degrees. Tom's broom is _in_ the corner, but you could stand _on_ or _at_ the outward corner of a building or street.

Comment: @KateBunting. Yes, I see what you mean. I deleted my confusing comment. A corner is a place defined by the intersection of walls, roads, etc.  You can lean a broom **in** the corner of a room, but you *can’t* lean a broom (or a roll of carpet) **on** the corner of a room. For the place defined by the intersection of two streets - here you can indeed be **on** a corner. You can also place an ornament **on** the corner of the mantelpiece. I cant find much logic in all this and suggest that the choice of preposition is simply a matter of idiom.